# Class method signature based on supplied type in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to reduce boilerplate on something I'm working on and wondering if something is possible - I suspect it's not but was looking for confirmation

```
class Something<T> {

private val list = mutableListOf<T>()

fun addToList(value: T) = list.add(value) }
```

So if I wanted to use this with a class like:

```
class Data(number: Int, letter: Char)
```

I'd have to use addToList like:

```
addToList(Data(1,"a"))
```

Is there some way to use the supplied type T to construct the method addToList dynamically? So that the class would be instantiated like:

```
val thing = Something<Data>()
```

but then addToList were called like

```
addToList(1,"a")
```

Like I said, don't think this is possible but was looking for confirmation.

What I was really trying to do was come up with something that would allow me to do this without declaring Data at all, but instead just define the structure and the subsequent addToList method when Something() was instantiated - not sure if I have described this all that well but if anyone has any suggestions in general around that I'd be grateful!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There are Pair and Triple tuple classes provided in the standard library which allows you to avoid declaring a class for simple combinations of values. If you need more than 3 parameters of different types, you'd need to create your own class or use a library that provides larger tuple classes. If all types are the same, you can use List instead of a tuple.

In my opinion even Triple is pushing it and anything with more than two distinct properties should just have its own data class defined.

```
class Something<A, B> {

    private val list = mutableListOf<Pair<A, B>>()

    fun addToList(valueA: A, valueB: B) = list.add(Pair(valueA, valueB)) 

}

val something = Something<Int, String>()
something.addToList(1, "a")
```

An alternate approach if you want to keep the flexibility of your Something class to hold anything would be to use an extension function.

```
class Something<T> {

    private val list = mutableListOf<T>()

    fun addToList(value: T) = list.add(value)

}

fun <A, B> Something<Pair<A, B>>.addToList(valueA: A, valueB: B) = 
    addToList(Pair(valueA, valueB))

val something = Something<Pair<Int, String>>()
something.addToList(1, "a")
```

Comment: There is a slight typo `something.add` -> `something.addToList`

Comment: Thanks, @Joffrey.

Comment: Appreciate the response - I was looking for something more dynamic though, so that addToList() would work regardless of the form of T. (I don't think the original post made this very clear.)

I suspect what I'm talking about, ie using information about the class T to dynamically create the method's signature is not possible. Cheers for the reply though!

Comment: @sturgeon You could do something with varargs and reflection, but the compiler would not be able to enforce that you pass the right number and types of parameters.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Ah yeah - I think that's the sort of thing I was thinking of but wasn't sure if it would be possible. Given the potential issues you point out though, I guess it's safer to go with the extra boilerplate. Thanks!